# Start And Stop Windows Service remotely using PSEXEC

Tags: windows-services, psexec

How to start and and stop a Windows service remotely using PSEXEC? Preferably the syntax to write I tried the cmdlet given below

```
psexec \\Server -u Administrator -p Somepassword ServiceName
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on serverfault.com?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but it ought to be:

```
psexec \\server -u username -p password net start ArgusCommunityWorkerService
```

and

```
psexec \\server -u username -p password net stop ArgusCommunityWorkerService
```

Answer (score 18):

[PSService on SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx) is specifically for remotely controlling services::`

```
psservice [\\computer [-u username] [-p password]] <command> <options>
```

where:

> **query** Displays the status of a service.
>
> **config**    Displays the configuration of a service.
>
> **setconfig** Sets the start type (disabled, auto, demand) of a service.
>
> **start** Starts a service.
>
> **stop**   Stops a service.
>
> **restart**   Stops and then restarts a service.
>
> **pause**  Pauses a service
>
> **cont**   Resumes a paused service.
>
> **depend**    Lists the services dependent on the one specified.
>
> **security**  Dumps the service's security descriptor.
>
> **find**  Searches the network for the specified service.
>
> **\\computer**  Targets the NT/Win2K system specified.

Include the -u switch with a username and password to login to the remote system if your security credentials do not permit you to obtain performance counter information from the remote system. If you specify the -u option, but not a password with the -p option, PsService will prompt you to enter the password and will not echo it to the screen.

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative to psexec is sc. You can use sc to start or stop services remotely:

```
sc \\server start ServiceName

sc \\server stop ServiceName
```

There is no "login" information, so maybe you need to execute

```
net use \\server password /USER:user
```

before executing sc command.

One advantage over psexec is that no console window shows in the remote machine.

Comment: Good one. I found I had to do: net use \\server\IPC$ password /USER:user

Answer (score 0):

**Using PSEXEC**

The below batch file will let you stop and start services on multiple remote machines. Create Computers.txt file in the same directory where the batch file runs from and list PC hostnames one per line.

```
@echo off
TITLE Manage Services v1.0
SET suffix=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
SET /P username=Enter your admin username: 
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
:service
SET /P servicename=Enter service name:
:begin
echo ========================================
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Stop
echo 3) Choose another service
echo ========================================
ECHO.
set /p op=Select an option:
if "%op%"=="1" SET action=start
if "%op%"=="2" SET action=stop
if "%op%"=="3" goto service

psexec "\\@%~dp0Computers.txt" -u %username% -p %password% -h net %action% %servicename% >>%suffix%.log 2>&1

pause
cls
goto begin
```

**Using PowerShell**

```
# Point the script to the text file with remote computers
$RemoteComputers = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\Computers.txt"

# sets service name
$Service = "uvnc_service"

# Counter for progress bar
$counter = 0

ForEach ($Computer in $RemoteComputers) {
    $counter++
     Try
         {
          Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing computers' -CurrentOperation $Computer -PercentComplete (($counter / $RemoteComputers.count) * 100)
          Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
          Get-Service -Name $Service -ComputerName $Computer | Restart-Service -Force -ErrorAction Stop
          Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),$computer" | out-file -append -filepath "$PSScriptRoot\success.log"
         }
     Catch
         {
          Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),$computer" | out-file -append -filepath "$PSScriptRoot\failed.log"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/psservice), an alternative is using **psservice**, which is part of **pstools** downloadable under following link:

[Download PsTools (2.7 MB)](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip)

If someone needs to

> **Start, stop, restart, etc... a Windows Service remotely**

as mentioned in the official reference from Microsoft, the appropriate command using the provided executable

> **PsService.exe**

could be something similar to following (Case 1 and case 2), if you are using **Windows PowerShell**

**Case 1: *User, who will perform the wished command (e.g. restart) after signed in, is remote computer user with appropriate rights***

> .\PsService.exe \\Remote-ComputerName-OR-ServerName -u
> 'RemoteComputerName-OR-ServerName\Remote-ComputerUser' -p
> 'Remote-ComputerUser-Password' restart ServiceName

**Case 2: *User, who will perform the wished command (e.g. restart) after signed in, is domain superuser (e.g. DomainAdministrator)***

> .\PsService.exe \\Remote-ComputerName-OR-ServerName -u
> 'DomainShortName\DomainAdministrator' -p
> 'DomainAdministrator-Password' restart ServiceName

PS: Notice in this case the **single quoted parameter values** for

username

> **-u**

and password

> **-p**

for complex password and/or username

That's it, your command should get executed smoothly, just be patient!